# Recursive join PostgreSQL finding all parent ids from child id

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a database that contains parent/child relationships and I am attempting to collapse the data so that a child id has all of its parent ids in the same row.

```
Name | ID | Parent_ID
A         1       NULL
B         2       1
C         3       2
D         4       3
```

I am attempting to achieve the following:

```
Name | ID | Top_Level   | Sub_Level | Sub_Level_2
A         1       NULL
B         2         1
C         3         1     2
D         4         1     2            3
```

I played around with some recursion but did not get the correct results and am not sure how to proceed. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
with recursive stuff as (

  select
    *
  from table
  where
    id = 4
  union
  select
    table.*
  from table
  join stuff on stuff.parent_id = table.id
)
select * from stuff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but I can't think of anything different right now:

```
with recursive stuff (name, id, parent_id, nodes, level) as (
  select name, id, parent_id, array[parent_id], 1 as level
  from t
  where id = 4
  union
  select c.name, c.id, c.parent_id, p.nodes||c.parent_id, p.level + 1
  from t c
    join stuff p on p.parent_id = c.id
), level_info as (
  select max(level) as max_level
  from stuff
), path_info as (
  select nodes as all_nodes
  from stuff
  where level = (select max_level from level_info)
)
select stuff.name, 
       stuff.id,
       stuff.level, 
       case 
         when level = max_level then null
         else all_nodes[max_level - 1]
       end as root,
       case 
         when level < max_level - 1 then all_nodes[max_level - 2] 
       end as sub_level,
       case 
         when level < max_level - 2 then all_nodes[max_level - 3] 
       end as sub_level_2
from stuff, path_info, level_info
order by id;
```

The recursive part collects the whole path for each node that is visited. We then need to calculate the longest path and the highest level in order to be able to find the top level and the two sub-levels. That's what the two other CTEs do.

I cross join them to the base CTE to be able to access the columns in there. As both CTEs only have a single row, the cross join doesn't change the result, but makes using those values easier.

It's probably not the most efficient way of doing that though.

Online example: http://rextester.com/KVOG87512